# Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I have an issue I cannot solve :

```
* Where:
Script '<path to project>\node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\fonts.gradle' line: 4

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Two options, either upgrade your gradle to a higher version, so android is available earlier, or downgrade your version of `react-native-vector-icons` to  below 9.1.

Doing this wraps the assets folder check in an `afterEvaluate` condition, so at this point android is available.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, Check your app/build.gradle and make sure that the "apply from ... fonts.gradle" is at the bottom of build.gradle

app/build.gradle

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```